# Need to POST Microsoft Graph resource "GroupPolicyCategory" or "GroupPolicyDefinition" without a category

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Can not find a way to POST Microsoft Graph resource "GroupPolicyCategory" or "GroupPolicyDefinition" without a category.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-grouppolicy-grouppolicydefinition?view=graph-rest-beta) it's impossible to Post a GroupPolicyDefinition so may be it's possible to upload the whole category.

Tried the request from this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-grouppolicy-grouppolicyuploadedcategory-create?view=graph-rest-beta):

`{ "error": { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Invalid OData type specified: \"microsoft.graph.groupPolicyUploadedCategory\".", "innerError": { "date": "2023-07-21T13:32:29", "request-id": "e24963dc-9278-434f-852b-0db293253f0e", "client-request-id": "1635bc49-5029-81af-a355-2567678e5826" } } }`

[Request Wiht Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzp42.png)
[Request Without Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90fb9.png)

Tried to use MSGraph SDK:

`{ "error": { "code": "No method match route template", "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/singleton/navigation with http verb POST for request /GroupPolicy/GroupPolicyAdminService/{someId}/deviceManagement/groupPolicyCategories.", "innerError": { "date": "2023-07-21T13:00:00", "request-id": {someId}, "client-request-id": {someId} } } } }`

Comment: I see the same behaviour. Since you are using the beta endpoint, there may be an issue with it. Keep in mind that beta endpoints are subject to change. I will dig further come back with what I find.